# Boostrap navbar menu "lagging"?

Tags: html, css, menu, web

Why does my navbar menu (bootstrap based) lagging while collapse in/out?

Link:
http://www.snjezana-varovic.com/v2/

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

If I remove float propertie on ul/li elements, and transition on the `#menu`, this is a bit smoother.
But I didn't managed to solved it all :/